# How do I prevent a child element from inheriting parent element's attached attribute (in notched navigation)?

Tags: css

I am building a notched navigation, in which a triangle "cut out" is used as a marker for the active li.

I would also like to have dropdowns that reveal dropdown content on hover.

When hovering over a "current" (active) li with a dropdown, the dropdown content displays the triangle "cut out".

How do I remove the triangle "cut out" (notch) from the dropdown content of the active li?

.

Please view codepen and hover over *Dropdown 2*:

http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/pbvxKr

CSS

```
.nav .current a:before,
.nav .current a:after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:2em; /* Let's call this our magic number... */
    height:2em; /* ...our notch will be half this size. We define it in ems to scale it up with the text size. */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-1em; /* Half of our magic number. */
}
```

HTML

```
      <li class="current">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.nav .current .dropdown-content a:before,
.nav .current .dropdown-content a:after { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have nested `<a>` tags in your HTML code. Your styles are set up to set all `<a>` tags with the `:before` and `:after`. You need to limit the styles to the first `<a>` tag.

Modify your code

```
.nav .current a:before { ... }
.nav .current a:after { ... }
```

with the following...

```
.nav .current > div > a:before { ... }
.nav .current > div > a:after { ... }
```

the `>` says only add the styles to the immediate child and nothing more.

Comment: Hi - I tried adding this .nav .current > .dropbtn > a:before, however, this only seems to remove the triangle cut-out (notches) completely.

Comment: @Wim Mertens figured it out - great explanation, though - this helped me think it through a little more clearly ... thank you!

Comment: You used the wrong class. It should have been `div` not `.dropbtn`